# What is better to use jquery Ui widgets or jquery plugins for similar things?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

What is better to use jquery Ui widgets or jquery plugins for similar things? in terms of performance, easy to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. The UI library has a fairly large download size, a penalty in terms of page load time. If you're going to use several features of the UI library I recommend you use it. If you just need one feature it's probably better to use a specific plugin so you do don't have to incur the penalty of the large download.

As you probably already know there are many plugins that do do the same things better and have a smaller footprint. But on the other hand having one consistent library is better for maintainability.